# Django force migrations/database syncing

Tags: python, django, migration

I had my migrations file in version control, and it went out of sync between production and development (I know, that was the mistake, but it's happened now).

As a result, I couldn't run migrations in production. I deleted the migrations folder, and then re-ran makemigrations and migrate. makemigrations logs out creating all the fields. However, migrate simply says "no migrations to apply", and the extra fields do not appear in the database.

All I've changed is adding nullable fields to a model, so it should be a straightforward migration.

I can drop the whole db and start over, but I'd prefer not to because it takes a long time to re-populate.

Is there a way that I can force Django to find the differences between the DB and the models, and build the correct migrations to add the fields?

I attempted adding nonsense models to try and trigger a refresh. But that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: The `django_migrations` table contains details of the last run migration on your DB. Check if the migration id is already added against the Django app whose models you want to migrate. If so, delete the entry from which you want to run the migration.

Comment: Ah, that's handy! Thanks!